# How to use Pkcs11Interop with an NitroKey HSM to derive an shared secret with an EC

Tags: c#, pkcs#11, hsm, pkcs11interop

I bought a NitroKey HSM and manged to create an EC on it.

Now I want to derive a shared secret.
I found [Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/), which seems to be the right tool for the job, but the handling is unclear.

A code snipplet or link to a working project would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [Pkcs11Admin](https://www.pkcs11admin.net/) application for a real world sample using Pkcs11Interop library.

As far as I remember NitroKey HSM should be used with [OpenSC middleware](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC) so your unmanaged library implementing PKCS#11 API will be `opensc-pkcs11.dll`.

I believe these resources might be helpful for you:

1. [Getting started with Pkcs11Interop](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/doc/GETTING_STARTED.md)
2. [Pkcs11Interop code samples](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/doc/CODE_SAMPLES.md) which contain also key derivation sample
3. [PKCS#11 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/raw/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf)

Comment: Thx for your contribution to Pkcs11Interop! I learned a lot from the Pkcs11Interop samples and Pkcs11Admin, but stuck at the point where I have an ObjectHandle of my private EC-Key and a byte array of a public EC-Key. I found this implementation https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/group__SEC__11__14__KEY__MANAGEMENT__FUNCTIONS.html but I was not able to adopt this. For example how so I get prime and base for my brainpool EC.

Comment: @dh_cgn Could I see your code and that byte array with public key?

Comment: @dh_cgn I am little confused from the sample but in general you first need to choose a suitable mechanism/algorithm for your use case. I guess you have chosen `CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE` but I am not sure why did you choose this particular one or whether it is the correct one for your use case. Anyway as a second step in general you need to read about the parameters of selected mechanism in PKCS#11 spec. It's chapter 12.4.10 in this case. If needed read also algorithm specs mentioned in PKCS#11 spec. It's PKCS#3 in this case.

Comment: As a third step when you understand the algorithm and its parameters, you just need to use the correct constructor of `Mechanism` class with the correct parameters and everything should be fine. BTW did you pick `CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE` intentionally?

Comment: I did choose CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE because the docu says: The PKCS #3 Diffie-Hellman key derivation mechanism, denoted CKM_DH_PKCS_DERIVE, is a mechanism for key derivation based on Diffie-Hellman key agreement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135508/discussion-between-dh-cgn-and-jariq).